# Within a circle, Find a probability distribution to model a random variable with distance to center and angle information

Tags: probability, distributions, circular-statistics

Within a circle with radius R, a random variable with two types of information as below:

1. Distance to the circle center. The distance should satisfy uniform distribution~U[a R], where 0<=a<R is a user-defined value.
2. Angle information. It should satisfy von mises distribution. [image]

Question: Is there any existing distribution which satisfy above-mentioned requirements?